# How to correct the count number after groupby?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, aggregate

I am trying to get a dataframe which has Date and Section to count the items in each Section per hour. I use the following:

```
new_df = df.groupby([pd.Grouper(key='Date',freq='H'),'Section']).agg(PPT=('Section','count')).reset_index()
```

The problem is that the count does not take into account the 0 values. I have tried so many variations of groupby and Grouper and could not solve it. I am trying to get the count for each hour according to each Section, even if the count if the count 0.

Please let me know if I was not clear, I will try to come up with example.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer in another thread: I added

```
.unstack(fill_value=0).stack().reset_index()
```